Converting Cartesian Coordinates to Horizontal Coordinates Relative to Rotation
There exists object A with a Cartesian position, forward vector, right vector, and up vector. There exists object B with a Cartesian position.
With the horizontal XY plane defined as the forward and right vectors of A, how can the horizontal coordinates of B from A (treated as the horizontal origin) be found?
For clarity, the XY plane should be synced with A's rotation. The difference between A's forward vector and the vector from A to B should yield azimuth and elevation relative to A's rotation.
Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Solved it! Here's the Desmos.
And here's the code:
Vector3 transmitterRight = transmitter.Basis.X;
Vector3 transmitterUp = transmitter.Basis.Y;
Vector3 transmitterForward = transmitter.Basis.Z;

Vector3 receiverDifference = receiver.Position - transmitter.Position;
Vector3 receiverDirection = receiverDifference.Normalized();

float projectedRight = receiverDifference.Dot(transmitterRight);
float projectedUp = receiverDifference.Dot(transmitterUp);
float projectedForward = receiverDifference.Dot(transmitterForward);

float radius = receiverDifference.Length();
float elevationRadians = Mathf.Asin(projectedUp / radius);
float azimuthRadians = Mathf.Atan2(projectedRight, projectedForward);

const float toDegrees = 180f / (float)Math.PI;
double elevationDegrees = elevationRadians * toDegrees;
double azimuthDegrees = azimuthRadians * toDegrees;

